# Curl Parallel requests using links source file

Tags: curl, xargs, http, parallelism, https

I have this script to go through a list of URLs and the check return codes using Curl.

Links file goes like this:

```
https://link1/...
https://link2/...
https://link200/...
(...)
```

The script:

```
INDEX=0
DIR="$(grep [WorkingDir file] | cut -d \" -f 2)"
WORKDIR="${DIR}/base"
ARQLINK="navbase.txt"


for URL in $(cat $WORKDIR/$ARQLINK); do

        INDEX=$((INDEX + 1))
        HTTP_CODE=$(curl -m 5 -k -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' $URL)

        if [ $HTTP_CODE -eq 200 ]; then
                printf "\n%.3d  => OK! - $URL" $INDEX;
        else
                printf "\n\n%.3d  => FAIL! - $URL\n" $INDEX;
        fi

done
```

It takes a little while to run through every URL, so I was wondering how to speed those up curl requests.
Maybe I could use some parallel Curl requests, but using "xargs" inside a "for" loop while also printing a message doesn't seem the way to go.

I was able to use "xargs" out of the script and it sort of works, although not showing the correct HTTP code.

```
cat navbase.txt | xargs -I % -P 10 curl -m 5 -k -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' %
```

I couldn't find a way to insert that into the script.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Curl 7.68 has the `--parallel`, `--parallel-max` and `--parallel-immediate` options. This would be the cleanest approach. See release notes [here](https://curl.se/mail/archive-2020-01/0011.html) and some man options [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html) .

Comment: I don't see how to fit this "parallel" option into my script. How would I feed Curl with a file URLs to run then in parallel and still print a message for each one?